# How can i tell if getOutputStream or getwriter was called in a servlet filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, filter

Is there a way to tell if `getOutputStream` or `getWriter` was called?

I'm implementing a servlet filter to modify response data using a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to wrap and store original response data. After manipulating  the data I need to write it back to the original response.

I find that I get an error using ether `getOutputStream` or `getWriter` depending on the request.
The filter itself is not used on my application so I can't control the code used to write the original response.

I also can't make sure my filter is the first to be called in the chain so I can't implement a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to keep track of whether getWriter or getOutputStream has been called.

for now what I did was

```
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(newData);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            response.getWriter().write(new String(newData,charset));
        }
```

it works but i never feel comfortable using exception for "normal" code flow.

Comment: can you explain more about your application and the other one ?

Comment: You mentioned that "i also cant make sure my filter is the first to be called in the chain". Why is that? Filters are applied in the same order as they're mapped in the web.xml, even if the filters themselves are created using annotations instead of being declared in the web.xml.

Comment: my application is working in html level. style analyzing and such. the filter is actually only used to connect to an API on our server.the fitter is to be used by our client there for i don't have any control the code or the filter order. we rerecorded using our filter first but the client insisted the have to run one of theirs first.

Comment: Just wrap the response and make sure you wrap return values from `getWriter` and `getOutputStream`. This is what many frameworks do, so I don't understand where your concerns come from.